# Trigger instead of и cascade delete

Tags: sql-server, sql

Если способ обойти ограничение на создание триггера типа **INSTEAD OF**, для таблицы с внешним ключом, и включенным **ON DELETE CASCADE**, если в триггере, после некоторых манипуляций, записи все равно будут удалены?  Обычный триггер не предлагать.

Comment: Честно говоря, не понял в чем вопрос. Вы хотите создать триггер, а вам не дают?

Comment: Да. Это ограничение MS SQL. INSTEAD триггеры на удаление и апдейт запрещается создавать на таблице, у которой есть внешние ключи с каскадными действиями

Comment: Спасибо, с переводом стало понятно.
Т.е. начало фразы вместо "Если способ..." нужно читать как "Есть ли способ...". :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет. 
Какой в этом случае смысл ON DELETE?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table1](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_table1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table2](
    [i] [int] NOT NULL,
    [id] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_table2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [i] ASC
)
) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table2]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_table2_table1] FOREIGN KEY([id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[table1] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table2] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_table2_table1]

GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[td_table1] ON [dbo].[table1]
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS

DELETE FROM table2
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM deleted)

DELETE FROM table1
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM deleted)

RETURN
```

А теперь тестовые данные

```
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (1),(2)
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (10,1),(11,1),(12,2)
```

Удаляем и смотрим, что выполнил триггер

```
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id = 1

SELECT * FROM table2
SELECT * FROM table1
```

Comment: При удалении записей в таблице А, каскадно удаляются записи в таблице В, ссылающиеся на удаляемые в А. Я хочу перед удаление записи в В, обновить ее.

Comment: Вставьте удаление в триггер

Comment: т.е все каскадные удаления перенести в триггер таблицы A?

Comment: Конечно, раз уж вы замещаете всю операцию удаления

Comment: > т.е все каскадные удаления перенести в триггер таблицы A? 

не обязательно все. те, которые относятся к непосредственно зависимым таблицам.

Answer (score 0):

Получается, что вам не нужен **ON DELETE CASCADE**. Тогда вам придется делать ссылочную целостность на триггерах.

Comment: Нет. Ссылку создать не возбраняется, достаточно не устанавливать на ней никаких действий

Comment: непонятен смысл *CASCADE*. к тому же, по умолчанию стоит *NO ACTION*, который не позволит ничего удалить из А. Триггер INSTEAD OF откатится.

Comment: Зачем ему откатываться? Тестовый сценарий добавил в свой ответ